# how can I set the background to continue after minimizing the tab

Tags: html, css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO6Gq.jpg

When I have something written or images on a tab and I minimize it, my background does not continue as I wanted. I've added the @media if needed. I don't know what to do more to solve this problem.
for this code:

```
.clima-section{
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(bg.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 260px;
  width: calc(100% - 260px);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.sidebar.close ~ .clima-section{
  left: 78px;
  width: calc(100% - 78px);
}
.clima-section .clima-content{
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.clima-section .clima-content .bx-menu,
.clima-section .clima-content .text{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 35px;
}
.clima-section .clima-content .bx-menu{
  margin: 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.clima-section .clima-content .text{
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .sidebar.close .nav-links li .sub-menu{
    display: none;
  }
  .sidebar{
    width: 78px;
  }
  .sidebar.close{
    width: 0;
  }
  .clima-section{
    left: 78px;
    width: calc(100% - 78px);
    z-index: 100;
  }
  .sidebar.close ~ .clima-section{
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we have your HTML?

Comment: <section class="clima-section">
    <div class="clima-content">
      <i class='bx bx-menu' ></i>
    </div>
<p>
text
</p>
</section>

Answer (score 0):

It has to due with the hight of the image. Try to add the value "repeat" on the "background-repeat property in css. Like so:

```css
.class {
background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Check this page for more information: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp

Comment: can u check my code?

Comment: Add this (background-repeat: repeat;) to --> .clima-section

Comment: hmm it didn't work ..